# Windows - Converting OpenSSL generated certificates

Tags: certificate, openssl, secure-boot

I'm following a [guide on how to enroll your own Secure Boot keys on Linux](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sakaki%27s_EFI_Install_Guide/Configuring_Secure_Boot_under_OpenRC) but my platform that I'm using is Windows and I'm currently stuck trying to convert the OpenSSL generated certificates into a format accepted by the BIOS.

In particular these two tools only available on Linux:

[sign-efi-sig-list](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/sign-efi-sig-list.1.html) - signing tool for secure variables as EFI Signature Lists

[cert-to-efi-sig-list](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cert-to-efi-sig-list.1.html)  - tool for converting OpenSSL certificates to EFI signature lists

I can generate the OpenSSL certificate using OpenSSL but I cannot find any equivalent tool on Windows which lets me convert an OpenSSL generated certificate (.crt) to an EFI signature list (.esl). Or convert an EFI signature list (.esl) to an authenticated signature file (.auth).

The [Github](https://github.com/mjg59/efitools) repository for EFITools which is just for Linux also seems broken.

Has anyone done this before?
Help much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to do it even with grawity's answer. So what I did instead was just use a virtual machine and install Ubuntu before using the Linux guide which was so much easier. I managed to enroll the keys in the end on my BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HP "Secure Boot Customization Guide"](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05649759), the equivalent commands are present in Windows 10 PowerShell (with examples copied as is from the PDF):

- Create an EFI Signature List: `Format-SecureBootUEFI`

  ```
  Format-SecureBootUEFI -Name PK `
                        -SignatureOwner DEF16466-F946-4E71-BE22-CF8B1B7B36A0 `
                        -ContentFilePath .\PK_SigList.bin `
                        -FormatWithCert `
                        -Certificate .\PK.CER `
                        -SignableFilePath .\PK_SigList_Serialization_for_PK.bin `
                        -Time 2016-02-01T13:30:00Z
  ```
- Sign the EFI Signature List: `signtool` (yes, UEFI Secure Boot is just Microsoft Authenticode)

  ```
  signtool.exe sign /fd sha256 /p7 .\ /p7co 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1 /p7ce DetachedSignedData
                    /a /f .\PK.PFX /p <password> PK_SigList_Serialization_for_PK.bin
  ```
- Create an authenticated SetVariable() package as a file: `Set-SecureBootUEFI`

  ```
  Set-SecureBootUEFI -Name PK `
                     -Time 2016-02-01T13:30:00Z `
                     -ContentFilePath .\PK_SigList.bin `
                     -SignedFilePath .\PK_SigList_Serialization_for_PK.bin.p7 `
                     -OutputFilePath .\PK_NewKey_Import_PK.bin
  ```
- Send an authenticated SetVariable() call to UEFI: also `Set-SecureBootUEFI`

  ```
  Set-SecureBootUEFI -Name PK `
                     -Time 2016-02-01T13:30:00Z `
                     -ContentFilePath .\PK_SigList.bin `
                     -SignedFilePath .\PK_SigList_Serialization_for_PK.bin.p7
  ```

I haven't tested this.